# plotting a decision tree based on gridsearchcv

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, cross-validation, data-science-model, grid-search

i was trying to plot the decision tree which is formed with GridSearchCV, but its giving me an Attribute error.

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'n_features_'
```

However if i try to plot a normal decision tree without GridSearchCv, then it successfully prints.

***code [decision tree without gridsearchcv]***

```
# dtc_entropy : decison tree classifier based on entropy/information Gain
#plotting : decision tree on information/entropy  based

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import graphviz

feature_names = x.columns

dot_data = export_graphviz(dtc_entropy, out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True,
                                feature_names=feature_names,  
                                class_names=['0','1','2'])
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph                           ### --------------> WORKS
```

***code [decision tree with gridsearchcv]***

```
#plotting : decision tree with GRIDSEARCHCV (dtc_gscv)  on information/entropy  based
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import graphviz

feature_names = x.columns

dot_data = export_graphviz(dtc_gscv, out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True,
                                feature_names=feature_names,  
                                class_names=['0','1','2'])
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph                            ##### ------------> ERROR
```

***Error***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-603524707f02> in <module>()
      6 dot_data = export_graphviz(dtc_gscv, out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True,
      7                                 feature_names=feature_names,
----> 8                                 class_names=['0','1','2'])
      9 graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
     10 graph

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in export(self, decision_tree)
    393         # n_features_ in the decision_tree
    394         if self.feature_names is not None:
--> 395             if len(self.feature_names) != decision_tree.n_features_:
    396                 raise ValueError("Length of feature_names, %d "
    397                                  "does not match number of features, %d"

AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'n_features_'
```

***code for decision-tree based on GridSearchCV***

```
dtc=DecisionTreeClassifier()

#use gridsearch to test all values for n_neighbors
dtc_gscv = gsc(dtc, parameter_grid, cv=5,scoring='accuracy',n_jobs=-1)

#fit model to data
dtc_gscv.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

One **solution** is taking the best parameters from gridsearchCV and then form a decision tree with those parameters and plot the tree.

However is there any way to print the decision-tree based on GridSearchCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't have a module named `graphviz` I can still try to help. Reading the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) for GridSearchCV, I can see that there's a attribute called `best_estimator_` that provides the estimator that was chosen by the search. By applying `.best_estimator_` to your sample code, it seems be working fine.

```
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
dot_data = export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True,  
                                class_names=['0','1','2'])
-------------------
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

With `.best_estimator_`

```
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
dot_data = export_graphviz(clf.best_estimator_, out_file=None, filled=True, rounded=True,  
                                class_names=['0','1','2'])
```

I get no error. I hope this helps

Comment: what does best_estimator_ return ?

Comment: From what I understand from reading the documentation it provides the estimator that was chosen by the search

Comment: Thanks...it worked....even understood... it returns the classifier with all the parameter and it's best values